# Mysql: Extract Data from 3 Tables using ON clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query related to fetching records from the combination of 3 tables in a way that the returned result will be fetched using the ON clause with the help of foreign keys.

Lets assume, I have three tables named **table1**, **table2**, and **table3**.

**Table:** table1

```
id   name   t2_id   t3_id
11   John   21      31
12   Doe    22      32
```

**Table:** table2

```
id   value
21   ABC-1
22   ABC-2
```

**Table:** table3

```
id   value
31   XYZ-1
32   XYZ-2
```

In table:table1, **t2_id** and **t3_id** are foreign keys representing id from table table2 and table3 respectively.

**Question:**

I want to extract the records from table1 but also get the values from table2 and table 3 using their foreign key present in table1.

**Desired Results:**

```
id   name   t2_value   t3_value
11   John   ABC-1      XYZ-1
12   Doe    ABC-2      XYZ-2
```

**What I have done right now:**

I have written the below query for doing this task but its not working.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.value AS t2_value FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.t2_id=table2.id);
```

The output of above query will be like this:

```
id   name   t2_value
11   John   ABC-1
12   Doe    ABC-2
```

But i want to combine the 3rd table value here too.

Kindly help

> Important Note: I want to do this using Single MySQL Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. You just need to add another `join` clause for `table3` and add the column you want from it to the select list:

```sql
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.value AS t2_value, table3.value.value AS t3_value
FROM   table1 
JOIN   table2 ON table1.t2_id = table2.id
JOIN   table3 ON table1.t3_id = table3.id
```